# TypeError when hosting React App on Azure

Tags: reactjs, azure

I'm working on a project that I'm trying to host on Azure. The back end service deploys and runs great. The front end project does not. When I deploy it, on accessing it I just get a blank screen and in the console it shows the error `TypeError: Object(...) is not a function`. The same thing happens if I locally do `npm run build` then `serve -s build`. However, if I just type `npm start` then it runs correctly and I can access it via browser. Am I doing something wrong in the project itself? Or is there something I need to do on Azure to get it to work?

Comment: what are the steps you're taking to deploy this?